# Docker-in-Docker build information

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration

When using [`docker:24.0.0-dind`](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/tags?page=1&name=24.0.0-dind) with `docker:24.0.0-cli`, to `docker build` without installing Git first, we get warning:

> WARNING: buildx: git was not found in the system. Current commit information was not captured by the build

**What information is captured if Git is installed before running `docker build`?**

```bash
# Git is not installed at this point
# "WARNING: buildx: git was not found in the system. Current commit information was not captured by the build"
docker build -t "$REGISTRY/without-git" .

apk add git
# Git installed. No more buildx warning.
docker build -t "$REGISTRY/with-git" .

docker push "$REGISTRY/without-git"
docker push "$REGISTRY/with-git"

# stdout: null
docker buildx imagetools inspect "$REGISTRY/without-git" --format "{{ json .Provenance.SLSA }}"

# stdout: null
docker buildx imagetools inspect "$REGISTRY/with-git" --format "{{ json .Provenance.SLSA }}"

# Explicit attestation, also stdout: null
docker buildx build -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/with-git-attested" --attest type=provenance,mode=max .
docker push "$REGISTRY/with-git-attested"
docker buildx imagetools inspect "$REGISTRY/with-git-attested" --format "{{ json .Provenance.SLSA }}"
```

Comment: What command exactly produces that error message?  You do usually need to check out your application code before you build it.  You rarely if ever need the Docker-in-Docker setup; why are you trying to run that specific image?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have added the exact sequence of steps in the post.

Answer (score 3):

Docker with 23 uses buildx by default and that one captures [provenance](https://docs.docker.com/build/attestations/slsa-provenance/) automatically, e.g., captures git VCS information. That is just a warning not an error, so build still completes successfully, only git provenance information is missing.

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't seem to attest by default so it still doesn't answer the question. Using `docker:24.0.0-cli` with `docker:24.0.0-dind`: `docker build -t "$REGISTRY/without-git" .; apk add git; docker build -t "$REGISTRY/with-git" .; $(: push to registry); docker buildx imagetools inspect "$REGISTRY/without-git" --format "{{ json .Provenance.SLSA }}"; docker buildx imagetools inspect "$REGISTRY/with-git" --format "{{ json .Provenance.SLSA }}"`. The `imagetools inspect` prints `null` to `stdout` with and without Git.

Comment: You have to be in a git repository for this to work, are you?

Comment: Good question, but yes, current directory is a Git repo with already existing commits (`git log` after `apk add git` shows commits). For context, this is GitLab CI where the repository is cloned to the working directory, but only Git isn't installed in the container by default.

Comment: Interestingly, explicitly making attestations doesn't work either (see updated post).